# What is the Android Pay equivalent to Apple's Passkit "backfields"?

Tags: android, android-pay

With Apple Wallet, there is a "top-level" array called `backfields`, into which a developer can put as many key/value pairs as he/she wants -- it's essentially a place to store additional data so that the front of the pass doesn't get cluttered up.

Is `infoModuleData.labelValueRows[]` Android Pay's equivalent?